# How to use CDI, to get token from request?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jax-rs

I have a filter like this where I validate a token, I want to transport this token outside this class, because I want this token in another class for a query.

```
@Override   
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
    // Get the Authorization header from the request
    String authorizationHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
    // Validate the Authorization header
    if (!isTokenBasedAuthentication(authorizationHeader)) {
        abortWithUnauthorized(requestContext);
        return;
    }
    // Extract the token from the Authorization header
    token = authorizationHeader.substring(AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME.length()).trim();
    try {
        // Validate the token
        validateToken(token);
    }
```

and i have a method in another class like this: where i need token?

```
@Inject
AuthenticationFilter auth;

@GET 
@Secured
@Path("/books") 
@Produces("application/json")
public List<Book> getBooks() { 
    TypedQuery<Book> query = em.createQuery("SELECT s.books from Student s where s.token = :token", Book.class);
    System.out.println("Token: ------- " + auth.getToken());
    query.setParameter("token",auth.getToken());
    List<Book> resultList = query.getResultList();
    return resultList;      
}
```

What is wrong with this inject to get token?

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your question. What problem exactly are you having?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to share request scoped info is use request attributes.

On the filter you can store the token as a property of the request context:

```
requestContext.setProperty(TOKEN_PROPERTY_NAME, token);
```

Request context properties are stored as attributes of the request, and the HttpServletRequest can be injected on your resource with the `@Context` annotation. So you can get the token, with a `request.getAttribute`

```
@Context
HttpServletRequest request;

@GET 
@Secured
@Path("/books") 
@Produces("application/json")
public List<Book> getBooks() { 
    TypedQuery<Book> query = em.createQuery("SELECT s.books from Student s where s.token = :token", Book.class);

    String token = (String) request.getAttribute(TOKEN_PROPERTY_NAME);

    System.out.println("Token: ------- " + token);
    query.setParameter("token", token);

    List<Book> resultList = query.getResultList();
    return resultList;      
}
```